# Selecting Adopt and Sign - DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi, docusignconnect

How to change default "Adopt Your Signature" automatically based on the signer?
For example, for email signers it should be defaulted to "SELECT STYLE", for inperson signers it should be defaulted as "Use Signature Pad Option".

How to set this method, using DocuSign settings or API code?

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this behavior is not currently possible with the DocuSign API. Currently you can enable or Disable signature adoption configurations via SETTINGS > SIGNING AND SENDING > SIGNING SETTINGS > SIGNATURE ADOPTION CONFIGURATION, however this is not an envelope level setting that can be specified depending on the type of recipient. This setting is considered to be an account level configuration.