# Set Signature Pad - DocuSign

Tags: c#, docusignapi

How to set Signature Pad in DocuSign Demo account.

I have already searched the internet but I can't find anything, can anyone help me.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this was partially answered on your other question here:
[Selecting Adopt and Sign - DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72699065/selecting-adopt-and-sign-docusign)

By only enabling the recipient to draw to sign, you can enforce the signature be made via a Signature Pad. Navigate to SETTINGS > SIGNING AND SENDING > SIGNING SETTINGS > SIGNATURE ADOPTION CONFIGURATION > Disable all forms other than "draw signature".

Depending on the type of Signature pad you are using to capture the signature, you may have different options of enabling this within your integration. Once you learn how to operate your Signature Pad device, enabling it to sign signatures should be a seamless process.